# Rendering Images inside PDF, images not being rendered in PDF Viewer 0.1.8

Tags: itext, flying-saucer, pdfviewer

*Please check updates as they have additional informations... Apparently located the problem in a specific pdf client but cannot close the issue with an open bounty...*

I am generating a pdf using [grails rendering plugin](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/). The PDF has a couple of images inside and "some" of them are not being outputted!

I am rendering the images inline via data uris as [required by the plugin](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/7.%20Inline%20Images.html). That means that all my images are something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQECWAJYAAD...">
```

If I render them in a normal html view, I can see the images just fine! 
If I render the template to a JPG/PNG with the same plugin, again the images render all fine.

If I render to PDF the images which are being retrieved by an octed-stream are broken!

Something like:

[image]

Looks like the image started to render and then something happened...

It is happening on the big-sized images, but also on the thumbnail version of same image.

Any one has some hints as why this might occur?

**UPDATE**

The file which does not show up is a file with mime *application/octet-stream*
So apparently I can retrieve the bytes from the file, but when they transmitted for PDF Rendering, the image does not appear...

**Yet another update**
The issue seems to be related with the PDF Viewer. Was using a Linux based PDF Viewer (PDF Viewer 0.1.8) and specific images are broken. In all other PDF Viewers I could test everything works fine.
Cannot close the issue as there is a bounty open :( Sorry that the bounty and question seems meaningless now, but you never know, someone might have an idea how to solve this even for PDF Viewer 0.1.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQECWAJYAAD...">
```

works fine for me. Note the missing "e".

Comment: That e is added by: <rendering:inlineJpeg />.

Answer (score -1):

You can use rendering tag:

```
<rendering:inlineJpeg bytes="${your-image}" />
```

Make sure you **decodeBase64()** your image.